# How can I connect php files from different folders in php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Can you help me connect my php files from different folders..

I have a main folder sample then inside it I have 2 folders naming `0lib` and `Portal`.

Inside the folder `0lib` there is folder `amazon` and inside it there are folders `Mock`, `Model`, `Samples` and some `php` files like `Client.php` , `Model.php`

Inside the folder `Portal` I have the `productFeed.php`

I already connect those files using `include()` and `require()`. I also use autoload Class... They seems ok but when I run it the error says...

> **Fatal error:** Class 'amazon_Client' not found in /var/www/html/sample/0lib/amazon/Samples/SubmitFeedSample.php on line 68

The `SubmitFeedSample.php` is inside the folder `0lib->amazon->Samples->SubmitFeedSample.php`

**Here is my autoload Class codes:**

```
 function __autoload($className){
    $filePath = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
    $includePaths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
    foreach($includePaths as $includePath){
        if(file_exists($includePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePath)){
            require_once $filePath;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I think the auto load is the problem here.

Comment: So you have a class called `amazon_Client`, and you are trying to have it autoload `Client.php` in the `amazon` folder using `spl_autoload_register()`?

Comment: Yes Sir that is exactly what am I doing...

Answer (score 0):

I got your function to work as is by making one change:

```
function __autoload($className){
    $filePath = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
    $includePaths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
    foreach($includePaths as $includePath){
        // Assign the compiled file path here
        if(file_exists($classdir = $includePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePath)){
            // Don't use $filePath but rather newly assigned $classdir
            require_once($classdir);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

The function works, but I think you are missing the relative (or absolute) path. Try creating a `config.php` file that you can include on all your pages that will set the root path:

**root/config.php**

```
define("ROOTDIR",__DIR__);
spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
```

**root/some/document.php**

```
include_once(__DIR__.'/../config.php');

$test = new test_Test();
```

**function.__autoload()**

```
function __autoload($className)
    {
        $filePath = str_replace('_',"/",$className).'.php';
        // This would yield something like:
        // /data/19/2/133/150/2948313/user/3268049/htdocs/mydomain/test/Test.php
        $classdir = ROOTDIR."/".$filePath;
        if(file_exists($classdir)) {
            require_once($classdir);
            return;
        }
    }
```

**test_Test Class:**

This class would need to be here: `ROOTDIR.'/test/Test.php'`

Comment: Ok Sir I'll try this one..:)

Comment: You should echo the `$classdir` and see what that path is.

Comment: Your code works, for sure, I tried it on my system and it included the file. That being said, the running file was in the same directory as the folder that the class was in.

Comment: the path is amazon/Client.php

Comment: That's all? It should include the full include path, something like:  `/data/some/thing/user/123123/htdocs/amazon/Client.php` since you are using the `get_include_path()` function

Comment: Sir the file that I was running was in the folder Portal and Client.php was in 0lib as well as the other php files.

Comment: I think you are in need of a `config.php` file that is in your root folder that you can include in your main page to easily set the root path because I think all that is missing is the relative/absolute path to the class file.